# Node Unexpected token on script

Tags: javascript, function, token

Hello i was doing something to my site and when i added one function i made a
mistake so if you can help me find it.
the error is on );
Problem is on function(er, ro)); -> );

```
pool.query('UPDATE games SET psteamid = "", pname = "", pavatar = "", pskinsurl = "", pskinsnames = "", pskinsprices = "", pskins = "", ptp = "", passetids = "", trade_token = "" WHERE id = ' + pool.escape(removefromGame[k]['id']), function(er, ro));
```

i tried to fix it but i cant find error i tried removing ) but nothing..

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/Fi4zJgWq) here is a full function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
pool.query('UPDATE games SET psteamid = "", pname = "", pavatar = "", pskinsurl = "", pskinsnames = "", pskinsprices = "", pskins = "", ptp = "", passetids = "", trade_token = "" WHERE id = ' + pool.escape(removefromGame[k]['id']), function(er, ro) {
    //do stuff with args er and ro
});
```

The `(er, ro)` function is the callback of `pool.escape()`.
You need to add a body for it to work.

Comment: I did that now i got this error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
on this bracket 
    });
     ^

Comment: @Niixi from your pastebin, it looks like you are missing a closing `}` for your first `if`. Look over your syntax.